# If closest parent has a certain class then do something

Tags: jquery

I am iterating through jQuery objects and trying to use https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/.

```
                        $(".lists .list .lineone").each(function(index) {
                            var text = $(this).text();

                            if (text == "John Smith") {
                                $(this).closest(".list").addClass("hidden");
                            };
                            if (text == "John Smith" && !(this).closest(".list").hasClass(".hidden")) {
                                counter++;
                            };
                        });
```

I am getting an error that hasClass() doesn't exist? Why is this?

I am trying to check in the 2nd if statement that the current element it's closest parent element called `.list` if it also has the class `.hidden` and if so add to the counter.

Comment: You are missing `$` in your if condition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand to nikhil's comment, this should be the code

```
                     $(".lists .list .lineone").each(function(index) {
                        var text = $(this).text();

                        if (text == "John Smith") {
                            $(this).closest(".list").addClass("hidden");
                        };
                        if (text == "John Smith" && !$(this).closest(".list").hasClass(".hidden")) {
                            counter++;
                        };
                    });
```